# For Geb Page Object, when is the static content block initialized?

Tags: groovy, geb

When following the geb page object pattern, it is encouraged to create a static block of values that represent the elements on the page you are attempting to interface with. It is also good to create an at checker. Here is an example:

```
class SomePage extends Page{

    static at = {$(By.xpath("some header or something")).displayed}

    static content = {
        element1 {$(By.xpath("some xpath1"))}
        element2 {$(By.xpath("some xpath2"))}
        //so on and so forth
    }
}
```

Now I think I know the answer this question already but could not find the docs to back it up. I am pretty sure that the static content block is initialized once the "at checker" is called from a test script, but I am not sure. If what I am suggesting is true then that would mean something like this:

```
class SomePage extends Page{

    static at = {$(By.xpath("some header or something")).displayed}

    def someString

    static content = {
        element1 {$(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ${someString}"))}
        element2 {$(By.xpath("some xpath2"))}
        //so on and so forth
    }

    def setSomeString(String x){
        this.someString = x
    }
}
```

would be impractical right, or maybe even impossible? This is because in order to call "setSomeString" you need to call the at checker to tell the script which class to reference for method and variable calls, but if you call the at checker that means the static content becomes initialized.

Furthermore, if a webpage has content that doesn't show up upon initial arrival to the webpage, then you would not be able to put that content into the static content block either, since the at checker should be called as soon as you arrive on said webPage.

I am simply looking to confirm or deny that this is the behavior of geb page object. and I would be happy to hear answers describing best practice given the above situation.

also if there is a way to re-initialize the content, I would like to know that too, but I figure there is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A content definition is evaluated every time the result of the definition is requested:

```
def somePage = to SomePage //at checker is executed but the defintion for element1 isn't
somePage.element1 // closure defined for element1 is executed
somePage.element1 // and here again

// many lines of code which trigger additional content to show up on the page

somePage.element1 // closure defined for element1 is executed again
```

Comment: so to answer my question exactly, if the xpath defining somePage.element1 is defined by another string variable: someString for example
`element1 {$(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ${someString}"))}`
and that variable changes where you have "//many lines of code..." then element1 gets re-defined on the last line with the new value of the someString variable? Based on your answer I wasn't sure if you fully understood the question

Comment: I did fully understand the question and yes, the element1 "gets re-defined" in that case (even if saying that it's re-defined is a simplification because its definition is never "fixed", as I have mentioned in my response).